# Does terminal support mouse input similar to how VSCode does?

Tags: powershell, windows-terminal

A lot of times, I already have my hand on the mouse and just need to make a quick selection or move the cursor around **using** the mouse.

To do standard things such as place the cursor at a certain word and highlight one or more words. No different than VSCode, as shown in this example [HERE](https://i.imgur.com/2vAzmXW.gif)

To be clear, I am not talking about selecting strings that have out have been output by a previous command but the command currently being typed by, for example, PowerShell.

I did a lot of searching and could not come to a conclusion. Some sources say that such a feature is only available in a WSL Windows Terminal, while others say its available in everywhere on Windows Terminal but needs to be enabled first.

I don't use WSL at all but PowerShell.

Is there a way to do this in standard windows Terminal or at least where PowerShell and CMD are concerned?

Comment: Bash supports it on the Mac Terminal. I can't test whether Windows does. [Opt] Alt/click will set the current cursor position on Mac. You can highlight just by dragging, for copy/paste etc, but that doesn't move the cursor itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from [zadjii-msft](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/4268#issuecomment-575380106) on the microsoft terminal github:

> No, that's not something that won't work without cooperation of the commandline application that's running in the Terminal. For example, `bash` or `cmd.exe`. Those are the applications that are actually responsible for drawing the prompt and the input line. They would need to be modified to support clicking to set the cursor position. I'm not sure I know of any shell application that actually supports that tbh. You can confirm this by trying to run the equivalent commandline in a legacy console window - note that that mouse doesn't work like that in shells there either.
>
> `vim` is a classic example of a application that is mouse aware.

In short, no. While the terminal program does read mouse input, PowerShell and CMD themselves do not. And in PowerShell's case, the feature is officially [not-planned](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine/issues/1982)

---

That said, certain tools with their own built-in terminals do support moving the cursor with mouse click:

- VS Code's PowerShell terminal extension allows using Alt+Click to change the cursor position
- Windows PowerShell ISE is built into windows (though no longer updated), and allows normal clicking

Comment: Damn, that is a shame. I am glad VScode made the cut as I use allot too. Thanks for the thorough answer!

Comment: To add - I'm experimentally trying out "mouse click to move cursor" in https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/pull/15758. It's probably good enough for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

To add on to Cpt.Whale 's thorough answer, VSCode now supports cursor repositioning in several of its integrated terminals! As well as PowerShell, I tested all my VSCode IDEs and can verify this also works on:

- Git Bash
- Command Prompt
- Ubuntu (WSL)
- JavaScript Debug